# Ошибка индентации

Tags: python, python-3.x

код

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
import time

test = True
while test :

sleep ( 3 )
pyautogui.click ( 121, 89, duration = 1)
pyautogui.click ( 2179, 435, duration = 1 )
sleep ( 2 )
pyautogui.click ( 1311, 669, duration = 1 )
pyautogui.click ( 1698, 253, duration = 1 )
```

Ошибка:

```
File "test.py", line 12
    sleep ( 3 )
    ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block
```

Comment: Вам следует более подробно описать вашу проблему и ситуацию в которой вы с ней столкнулись

Comment: пробелы это важно !

Comment: Вопрос следует закрыть, потому что автор не читал ни учебника, ни сообщения об ошибке.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyautogui
from time import sleep
import time

test = True
while test :

    sleep ( 3 )
    pyautogui.click ( 121, 89, duration = 1)
    pyautogui.click ( 2179, 435, duration = 1 )
    sleep ( 2 )
    pyautogui.click ( 1311, 669, duration = 1 )
    pyautogui.click ( 1698, 253, duration = 1 )
```

почитайте об [отступах](https://pythonchik.ru/osnovy/python-tabulyaciya-otstupy) в Python